# Databinding to last entry in each KeyValuePair<string, List<T>>

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a simple OHLC object that implements INotifyChanged. Each OHLC object relates to a particular candle and is part of a List. Each List relates to a particular stock and is stored in a ConcurrentDictionary<string, List>.

I'm trying to databind the last candle for each stock to a datagridview. This is how I have the databinding set up to get going. It's not very elegant!

```
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<OHLC>> candles= new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<OHLC>>();
    BindingList<OHLC> LastCandles = new BindingList<OHLC>();

    . . .
    form1.dataGridView1.DataSource = LastCandles;
    . . .
    public void OnUpdate()
    {
        //Update the appropriate candles
        . . .
        //Pull out the last candle by symbol and re-bind
        BindingList<OHLC> lastBySymbol = new BindingList<OHLC>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<OHLC>> dict in candles)
        {
           if (dict.Value.Count > 0)
           {
               lastBySymbol.Add(dict.Value.Last());
           }
       }

       LastCandles = lastBySymbol;

       form1.dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
       {
           form1.dataGridView1.DataSource = LastCandles;
           form1.dataGridView1.Refresh();
       });
   }
```

What's the best way to set up databinding here, so that I can just concentrate on updating the collection and not have to re-bind on each update? I can throttle a call to datagridview.Refresh() so it doesn't go repainting on every atomic update, but don't want to have to rebind.

I know how to databind once to a BindingList of custom objects and get the updates propagated to the UI with INotifyPropertyChanged and a simple call to datagridview.Refresh(). I can also find some examples in XAML which show databinding to the last item in a BindingList. But I can't find any examples that bind to the 'last-per-key' of a dictionary of lists.

I'd appreciate any help at all with this.

Comment: The only thing that matters is how you set the `List<OHLC>` in your `ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<OHLC>>` from what appears to be a secondary Thread. If you don't replace the `List<OHLC>` entirely, creating a new object, but you simply update existing members, the Binding also works cross-thread.  If you instead replace the `List<OHLC>` in the Dictionary, creating a new object, data binding of course doesn't work, simply because you have destroyed it. -- You can set your BindingList to, e.g., `LastCandles.Add(Candles["First"].Last()); LastCandles.Add(Candles["Second"].Last()); [...]`

Comment: ... when you first initialize the BindingList, possibly before you set the DataSource of the DataGridView. -- If you add new Keys to the dictionary, also add the new `Last()` object to the BindingList (this object will be updated later, from the secondary Thread). -- This: `form1.dataGridView1.[...]` is not a good thing at all. Also, don't `BeginInvoke()` a Control, always use the parent Form container as the marshaller.

Comment: I can try filling up the ConcurrentDictionary during initialization, then populating the BindingList with the last OHLC object for each key, and then setting the datasource to the BindingList. But when a new candle arrives and a new OHLC objects is added to a List<OHLC> for a particular key in the ConcurrentDictionary, won't the binding be lost as Last() will have changed?

Comment: *The only thing that matters is how you set the List<OHLC> in your ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<OHLC>>*: yes, it does. That's why the *introduction*. If that's the case, you can use an `IProgress<T>` delegate to update the UI when you add new members to the Dictionary or the `Last()` entry of an internal List change (not if you modify property values of members of the Lists). The delegate method can be:  `private void UpdateLastCandles() { LastCandles.Clear(); foreach (var list in Candles.Values) { LastCandles.Add(list.Last());  }`. You're just adding references.

Comment: Following this logic, you could use an intermediate object for data binding: another Dictionary that only contains ONE List member, which is updated using the property values of the `Last()` entry of each List in the main collection. In this case, you don't need to do anything, the data binding will work forever without the need of any direct update of the content of the `LastCandles` BindingList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This would be a WPF solution to the problem, not WinForms.

Don't transform your data to fit the view, create a value converter to handle that transformation.

```cs
[ValueConversion(typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable), typeof(object))]
public class LastItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)value)?.Cast<object>().Last();

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Then apply the conversion using data bindings:

YourControl.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class YourControl : UserControl
{
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<OHLC>> Candles { get; } = ...;
}
```

YourControl.xaml:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.YourControl"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <local:LastItemConverter x:Key="lastItemConverter" />
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Candles}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key"
          Binding="{Binding Key}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value"
          Binding="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource lastItemConverter}}" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Trigger updates as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was doing this in WinForms, but will switch to WPF so that I don't need to rearrange the ViewModel again to suit what I want to display.

Comment: Ah shoot, sorry I saw the code and thought it was for WPF. WinForms has similar mechanisms though I can't remember them off hand. I'll come back to this for a proper WinForms solution. But I believe you can still use the same converter.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms' `DataGridView` has a way to override the way it formats the data through the `CellFormatting` event. Handle that event so you could change the value that will be used for the column. You could also style the cell from here as well if you wanted to.

```cs
form1.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting;

//...

private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    switch (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
    {
    case "Value": // assuming this is the corresponding column name
        if (e.Value is List<OHLC> asList)
        {
            var lastValue = asList.Last();
            e.Value = lastValue;
            // example of additional styling
            if (lastValue.CostSavings > 0)
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```